# error:open fail:EROFS(Read-only file system)

Tags: android, file, text, io, android-emulator

i want to create file for write/read

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Hello);
    String str="my name is ";
    String FileName="myFile";
    File f=new File(FileName);
    try {
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            Boolean result= f.createNewFile();
            text.setText(result.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        text.setText(e1.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

BUT say error:open fail:EROFS(Read-only file system)

i use this emulator:
[image]

is this error for emulator!?

Answer (score -1):

Try checking if createNewFile() succeeds or not.

```
boolean result = f.createNewFile();
```

If file already exists, result above would be false. If you want to make sure that a new file is created, try:

```
f.delete()
boolean result = f.createNewFile();
```

Also make sure that a previous setText() such as "File create error" is not overwritten, since your exception handling does not stop the follow-on code to execute.

Comment: first catch say error:open failed:EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: Try this: # mount -o rw,remount /system. After you are done, do this: # mount -o ro,remount /system. This way, you can mount the filesystem as read-write.

Comment: I'm a beginner,please more explain,how mount -o rw?i use avd and eclipse for run app

Comment: No.  Do not remount /system - you can't normally do that, and even if you could application code is not allowed to write there, nor should it be trying to do.  The problem is that the poster is trying to write their file in an inappropriate place, probably the root directory of the device as a result of failing to specify any other location.